# Enabling encryption at install time: whole disk or partition only

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, partitioning

This is about installing and encrypting Ubuntu while having multiple partitions for dual boot.

When you install Ubuntu and tick the box *encrypt the new ubuntu installation*, is this going to encrypt the whole hard drive/SSD or rather the partition you are installing Ubuntu in? 
That is, will an existing Windows installation in another partition be affected in any way by enabling Ubuntu's encryption?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe it's just the part that has to do with Ubuntu... as this is the part you need it to work with

Answer (score 2):

If you tell the installer (Ubiquity) to install Ubuntu alongside the Windows OS (ie. leave Windows or any other OS intact), the only thing that will be encrypted is the partition(s) that your new Ubuntu installation resides on, not including the boot partition(s). The rest of your disk will be unaffected and left in it's current encrypted/non-ecrypted state.

To be more precise, if you let it use LVM like it wants to, in addition to the boot partition(s), a single partition will be created and encrypted with LUKS. That LUKS partition, in it's decrypted state, will contain an LVM physical volume which is allocated to a single LVM volume group. That volume group is then divided up into one or more LVM logical volume partitions upon which Ubuntu is installed.